# Format number with leading zeroes in .NET 2.0

Tags: vb.net

I have problem to format numbers and convert it to string with leading zeroes when application uses NET framework 2.0 with Visual Basic.

I try:

```
Dim myNum = 12
Dim myStr as String

Dim myStr = myNum.ToString("0000")
or
Dim myStr = myNum.ToString("D4")
```

... in order to get wanted string: 0012

Please help to solve this.

Comment: Have you tried either code snippets?  `myStr = myNum.ToString("D4")` is what you want.

Comment: So if you're not getting that result from the above code (both "D4" and "0000" will work) then something else is wrong and there's not enough information to help you.

Comment: @Tim, That don't work on my system. Message "Invalid format specifier" appear. On other computer with .NET framework 4.5 and windows 7 that work OK but on those with windows XP and .NET framework 2.0 NOT!

Comment: Hmm...I've run both methods on my system targeting .NET 2.0 (VS 2012 and Win7) and they worked as expected.  Is that your complete code?

Comment: OK, I find workable solution, thank's for trying to help: myNum.ToString.PadLeft(4, ChrW(48)). Also, on that machine I have VS2008.

Comment: Glad you found a solution, but you might want to dig a little if you have time to see what the root cause for the format strings not working is, otherwise you may run into further issues down the line.

Comment: Not so important at this time since I'm in hurry. There is some error with IFormatProvider in same cases but I haven't time to dig now and also solution with PadLeft seem's to work reliable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an old version of Visual Studio, one that doesn't have `Option Infer` yet.  Or it isn't turned on.  That makes the *myNum* identifier a variable of type `Object`.

So your code tries to call the Object.ToString() method.  Which does not have an overload that takes an argument.  The compiler now tries to make hay of your code and can only do so by treating ("0000") or ("D4") as an array index expression.  Indexing the string that's returned by Object.ToString().  That has pretty funny side effects, to put it mildly.   A string like "0000" is not a valid index expression, the compiler generates code to automatically convert it to an Integer.  That works for "0000", converted to 0 and the result is a *character*, just "1"c.  Converting "D4" to an integer does not work so well of course, that's a loud Kaboom!

The solution is a very simple one, just name the type of the variable explicitly:

```
  Dim myNum As Integer = 12
  Dim myStr = myNum.ToString("D4")    '' Fine
```

VB.NET's support for dynamic typing is pretty in/famous.  Meant to help new programmers getting started, it in fact is an advanced technique given the myriad ways it can behave in *very* unexpected ways.

The universal advice is always the same.  Let the compiler help you catch mistakes like this.  Put this at the top of your source code file:

```
 Option Strict On
```

Comment: Thank you Hans for this fully qualified explanation. It is privilege to learn from you.